# Kusznetov trace formula deduction in Iwaniec-Kowalski

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

I don't see how the authors deduce Theorem 16.9 of Iwaniec-Kowalski.  They say in the line just before that they, after Cauchy-Schwarz, put (16.56) and (16.69) in (16.43) and it comes out, but I can't see it.  After Cauchy-Schwarz we have as far as I can see terms like
\[ \sum _\mathfrak a\int _{\pm \infty }\frac {|\tau (t,m)|^2dt}{t^3\cosh t}\]
whereas they seem to have
\[ \sum _\mathfrak a\int _{\pm \infty }\frac {e^{-(t/T)^2}|\tau (t,m)|^2dt}{\cosh t}.\]
What am I seeing wrong, or what am I missing?  I don't really understand the summation, so it's possible I'm missing something there, or I may be missing a bounding trick with $e^{-t^2}$.

Comment: The estimate (16.56) is used to show (via positivity) that
$$\sum_{t_j \leq T} \frac{|\rho_j(n)|}{\cosh \pi t_j} + \sum_{\mathfrak{a}} \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{-T}^{T} \frac{\tau_{\mathfrak{a}}(n,t)|^2}{\cosh \pi t} \, dt \ll T^2 + \cdots.$$
So by breaking up the first two terms on the right-hand side of (16.43) into dyadic intervals and applying this bound, we get Theorem 16.9.

Comment: ah, great, thanks a lot for that!